# understanding dependency injection and IoC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

From what I gained so far, DI says don't let a class instantiate it's collaborators.

But again, there is this thing called [static cling](http://deviq.com/static-cling/) which is said to introduce undesirable coupling.

I have a scenario like the following:

context.cs

```
 class context
 {
     private readonly IStrategy _strategy;

     public context(IStrategy strategy)
     {
        _strategy = strategy;
     }

     public void execute()
     {
       _strategy.execute();
     }
```

strategy.cs

```
public class strategy: IStrategy
{
  ...
  public void execute()
  {
    ...
    var int testInput = 1;
    helperMethods.DoThatOtherThing(testInput);
    ....
 }
```

From what I understand, `strategy.cs` is a concrete implementation, so calling the static method is not bad after all.

what others are saying? am I in the right track?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  How do you change the behavior of DoThatOtherThing during tests?  If you're using a DI container, why have statics at all?  Let it configure your object with the supports it needs at runtime.

Comment: The only reason, so far, why you should make a DI is to avoid complexity or restriction on your testing (unit tests). So if you have method that saves a image, the saving is different on different devices. A mobile phone (winphone) has a differnt way to save the image than a surface.

Comment: The DI (or strategy pattern) uses the advantages of inheritance and implementation (of interfaces).

Comment: so what's the right way to do it? make `DoThatOtherThing` a private method of my strategy class? helperMethods only contains helper methods. or make helperMethods non static and inject it into strategy class?

Comment: You might want to improve the title of your question. Your current title will make it impossible for your question to become a googlable solution for others.

Comment: @Steven you are free to suggest an edit.